# How to route short tag to external web site

Tags: plugin-development, routes

I am writing a plugin to that will map http://short.com/e9DG to http:/longdomainname.com/longsubpagename

I assume I need to use the config/routes.php but am having struggling to understand how how to set this up. I keep getting 404 as it cannot resolve the url.

As a test I have the foloing code

```
return array(
    'e9DG' => array('action' => '/cocktailrecipes/ingredients/new'),
);
```

Answer (score 3):

With the [`registerSiteRoutes`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#registerSiteRoutes) hook you can route http://short.com/e9DG requests to any template.

```
public function registerSiteRoutes()
{
    return array(
        'e9DG' => '/mysection/mytemplate.html',
    );
}
```

With [`getUrl`](https://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/HttpRequestService) and [`redirect`](https://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/HttpRequestService) accessible via [`craft()->request`](https://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/HttpRequestService) you can set up server redirects:

```
$url = craft()->request->getUrl();

if ($url == 'http://short.com/e9DG')
{
    craft()->request->redirect('http:/longdomainname.com/longsubpagename', true, 301);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Shortener](https://github.com/aberkie/craft-shortener) and [Reroute](https://github.com/davist11/craft-reroute/) for inspiration as well ( might save you some trouble if you're just trying to write a general URL shortener!)